# how to make outer glow effect around a bitmap?

Tags: android, blur, glow

I created glow effect for my bitmap imageview. Its working but I have porblem with my outer glow color.

This is my expected design outer glow color:

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/professional-3d-carousel-as2-and-as3.html please see the link

but my glow effect not looking good please help me how make expected glow effect?
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int margin = 24;
        int halfMargin = margin / 2;

        // the glow radius
        int glowRadius = 16;

        // the glow color
        int glowColor = Color.rgb(0, 192, 255);

        // The original image to use
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // extract the alpha from the source image
        Bitmap alpha = src.extractAlpha();

        // The output bitmap (with the icon + glow)
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + margin,
                src.getHeight() + margin, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // The canvas to paint on the image
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(glowColor);

        // outer glow
        paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, Blur.OUTER));
        canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, halfMargin, halfMargin, paint);

        // original icon
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, halfMargin, halfMargin, null);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }


}
```

I am new for android i need programmatically only.....

[image]

expected glow in my backside of the imageview please see my expected screen shot: 
[image]